# CSS Media Queries issue with different 1280 resolutions

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to create a responsive layout and using CSS media queries to make it fit in various screen resolutions.
But when I made created Media Queries for below mentioned resolutions:

```
/*1280 x 1024*/
/*1280 x 960*/
/*1280 x 800*/
/*1280 x 768*/
/*1280 x 720*/
```

Being same width, the broswer picks the last "720px" css only

Here is my code:

```
    /*1280 x 1024*/
 @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) and (max-height: 1024px) and (min-height: 961px) {
    .resolution {
        color:#0000ff;
    }
}
/*1280 x 960*/
 @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) and (max-height: 960px) and (min-height: 801px) {
    .resolution {
        color:#00ff72;
    }
}
/*1280 x 800*/
 @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) and (max-height: 800px) and (min-height: 769px) {
    .resolution {
        color:#1e00ff;
    }
}
/*1280 x 768*/
 @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) and (max-height: 768px) and (min-height: 721px) {
    .resolution {
        color:#ff00f0;
    }
}
/*1280 x 720*/
 @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) and (max-height: 720px) and (min-height:300px) {
    .resolution {
        color:#fffc00;
    }
}

<div class="resolution">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

Please suggest!!!

Comment: You should always use EM instead of PX when working with media queries

Comment: People with low vision or with hand tremors use the page zoom and would love to get a decent layout

Comment: @jantimon maybe I don't write my point in the right way, I just have to be against the word "always" ... just because EM requires more calculations and considerations aobut handle default font-size browsers in some cases. There are some pro and cons for each `px` and `em` just apply in the specific case you have I say.

Comment: Sorry.. my bad.. the issue is with all Browsers

Comment: @Danko [Which CSS measurements to use when](http://demosthenes.info/blog/775/Which-CSS-Measurements-To-Use-When)

Comment: Adding to jantimon's comment, people who want to zoom _want to zoom_. Or resize their window.

Answer (score 1):

I put your code into a new HTML file and tested it at different resolutions. It seems to be working fine. Here's a screencast:
http://screencast.com/t/LdtVNqDDP

[Here's](http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/) a link to the browser addon you see me using in the screencast.

Comment: Thanks for creating annimation and fiddle, strange its working there, Request you  guys to please create a small HTML file, add the STYLE and DIV I provided and then change the Computer's Screen resolution and then please test if its still working for you guys?? cox its not working for me still!!!

Comment: I didn't create an animation, per se. What I did was put your code into a local copy and then did a screencast of my computer using Jing (a program for doing screencasts). So that animation you see is actually me clicking on different resolutions.

It's working for me in my local copy not only when I use the responsive design breakpoint tool I mention in my answer but also when holding down CTRL (CMD on Mac keyboards) and using my mousewheel to change the zoom.